# Why is move_uploaded_file not working?

Tags: php, file-upload, file-io

Whenever I try to move a file it does not work and shows "Image file not uploaded"... I just want to know where the error is...

```
$target = '/var/www/student/public/myimage.jpg';
$destination = '/var/www/student/public/images/myimage.jpg';

if( move_uploaded_file( $target, $destination ) ) {
    echo "Image file is successfully loaded";                           
} else {

   echo "Image file not uploaded.";
}
```

- I have checked error log (`tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log`) but found nothing.
- target and destination both directories have **777** permissions.

Can someone tell me that how to find out the error. Any idea ?

Comment: What is the *actual* code you are using? The code you provided will obviously not work because *target* must have been *uploaded via PHP's HTTP POST upload mechanism*.

Comment: Why is this tagged zend-framework?  And you're using the function wrong.  Read the php docs on it (http://php.net/move_uploaded_file).

Comment: File is already uploaded by other script and I am moving this file to other folder in server...

Comment: @Student you can't use move_uploaded_file to others uploaded content. You have to use rename like they suggested below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are not using HTTP POST upload method then you can use `rename()`

```
rename($target, $destination);
```

Comment: Yes. File is already uploaded to server by other script. I was just moving it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Has the file been uploaded in the current request?

`move_uploaded_file` will refuse to move files that are not uploads. (i.e. `$target` must equal `$_FILES[$field_name]['tmp_name']`

If it has been uploaded previously, `move_uploaded_file` will refuse to work (if it is even still there - PHP will delete it if you don't handle the file on that upload if I remember correctly)

If it is in fact *not* a file that has been uploaded with this request you'll want to use `rename`

Comment: if it's been uploaded to another page, it will have already been deleted by the time you try to call this, _and_ `move_uploaded_file` would refuse to work even if it was still there. You have to handle the uploaded file on the request where it is uploaded otherwise PHP will delete it if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 0):

move_uploaded_file() only works on http post files. http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

to move a file already on the server, you will have to copy the file and unlink the old file

```
$target = '/var/www/student/public/myimage.jpg';
$destination = '/var/www/student/public/images/myimage.jpg';
if (copy($target, $destination)) {
   unlink($target);
} else {
   echo "Unable to copy $target to $destination.";
}
```

Comment: There's even an optimized version. It's called [rename](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php).

Comment: -1: To move a file, you use `rename()`, not `copy()`. On large files, there is a big difference between the two. `rename()` simply modifies the file table to point to the new location; `copy()` creates a completely new copy of the file.

Comment: Copy is a valid option because sometimes you only have read permissions on a file. Rename will not work on a file with read permissions. I have run into times when I could not grant permission on a file unless I have had root access.